Staggered diff-in-diff vs Stacked diff-in-diff
Just trying to better understand what really is the technical difference between staggered diff-in-diff and stacked diff-in-diff. I understand that TWFE staggered DiD has its own troubles and that several authors have come up with ways to arrive at a more accurate estimate of ATT. But I also know that some authors rely more on stacked DiD design and I want to better understand the difference. My prior is that stacked DiD does not allow already treated units to be used as controls, while staggered DiD does? But not sure. Thanks.
